# Should I separate my POCO objects and Data Access Methods into separate class libaries?

Tags: c#, .net, repository

Should I structure my projects, so one class library only contains POCO objects and another class libraries contains the Data Access methods to do CRUD operations against these POCO objects?

Is this overkill to separate them out? or is there some benefit that can be achieved.

Options 1

- Data Access - Class Library
- Models - Class Library

Option 2

- Data Access, Models - Class Library

Comment: separation provides re-usability of POCOs. Is there a business logic layer that use those POCOs? If yes, keeping them separate is good

Comment: You are best advised to start off with Option 1 and move to Option 2 if you find you actually ever need it.